# Google App Engine: Sendmail, command not found

Tags: google-app-engine, sendmail

I'm trying to get sendmail working on localhost. The problem is that the app engine has det wrong path to sendmail, since it throws the error: /bin/sh: sendmail: command not found

Using Mac OS X, the path to sendmail is: /usr/sbin/sendmail

Does anyone know how to change this?

..fredrik

Answer (score 14):

I don't know how to change it but a symlink will do the job. I had the same problem and this solved it:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/sbin/sendmail /usr/bin/sendmail
```

Another option is to configure your local AppEngine runtime to [use an external SMTP server](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver.html#Using_Mail).

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation,

> The web server will use the sendmail
>   command to send email messages, with
>   your installation's default
>   configuration

If it uses NETINFO to determine the location of sendmail, the full path to sendmail.cf is stored as the value of the "sendmail.cf" property in the "/locations/sendmail" subdirectory of NETINFO, so try to set the value of this property to "/usr/sbin/sendmail.cf" (without the quotes)

Hope it helps